# Is it possible to clear node.js require cache using express.js?

Tags: node.js, express, require, reload

I wrote node.js small app for myself which was using small js code to clear require cache before handling request:

```js
let clearCache
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  const {cache} = require
  clearCache = (except) => {
    for (let key in cache)
      if (!except.includes(key) && key.indexOf('/node_modules/') === -1)
        delete cache[key]
  }
} else {
  clearCache = () => {}
}

const { createServer } = require('http')
const persistentPaths = ['/path/to/my/db/file']
createServer((req, res) => {
  clearCache(persistentPaths)
  require('./handleRequest')(req, res)
}).listen(3000, () => {})
```

I believe this is the most efficient way to working with app in development.

When I change code it applies immediately and this worked fine to me.

Now I would like to work with express.js, and it seems to impossible to use this approach.

Okay, seems like it is self-answering question and I need to use nodemon.

But I really don't want to use tool which will be watch all files and will relaunch whole server. I'm afraid that it would be much slower.

In my example you can see that I reload files except db file, so my app in development connects to database only once and keeps that connection. In case of using nodemon app need to load also all node_modules code, make new connection to db each time when code changed, maybe it will connect each time to postgres and to redis.

Question is: I can't be the one who doing it this way, are there solutions to reload modules for  express.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it! Would be glad if you will share your thoughts on it.

Because I can google only nodemon and chokidar solutions, maybe I'm doing something wierd, here is my solution:

server.ts:

```js
import express from 'express'
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.listen(port, () =>
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
)

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  const {cache} = require
  const persistentFiles: string[] = []
  const clearCache = (except: string[]) => {
    for (let key in cache)
      if (!except.includes(key) && key.indexOf('/node_modules/') === -1)
        delete cache[key]
  }
  app.use((req, res, next) => {
    clearCache(persistentFiles)
    const {router} = require('config/routes')
    router.handle(req, res, next)
  })
} else {
  const router = require('config/routes')
  app.use(router.handle)
}
```

And routes.ts:

```js
import {Router, Request, Response} from 'express'
export const router = Router()

router.get('/', function (req: Request, res: Response) {
  res.send('Hello world')
})
```

Usage: NODE_ENV=development NODE_PATH=src node src/server.js

(my IDE compiles ts to js while editing and put it right there, if you are using VS code it might be more complicated, I guess)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write your one util. You can use module like chokidar for so. You can specify directory and ignore the same time.

You can reload on callback the watch.

**Sample from there wiki:**: https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar

```
const chokidar = require("chokidar");

// Full list of options. See below for descriptions.
// Do not use this example!
chokidar.watch("file", {
  persistent: true,

  ignored: "*.txt",
  ignoreInitial: false,
  followSymlinks: true,
  cwd: ".",
  disableGlobbing: false,
  awaitWriteFinish: {
    stabilityThreshold: 2000,
    pollInterval: 100,
  },

  ignorePermissionErrors: false,
  atomic: true, // or a custom 'atomicity delay', in milliseconds (default 100)
});
// One-liner for current directory
chokidar.watch(".").on("all", (event, path) => {
  // Reload module here.
});
```

Comment: Chokidar makes overhead: it's separate process, have to watch many files, adds additional delay between code edit and reload, that's why I'd like to not use it
Thanks for reply, however, you did not show how to use chokidar to reload express app code, only how to use chokidar

Comment: reloading is simple to require again. and watch works like that, either pull or push. Here Push not possible, you have to pull on certain time stamp. You can reduce the frequency in config.

Comment: and here is chokidar code, it does not create thread for each file.. where u see thread in node js ??
https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar/blob/master/lib/nodefs-handler.js

Comment: node js is single thread framework. So u don't create a thread in nodejs code. Unless u use worker module. havent used here.

Comment: but I did not use word thread, only process of whole chokidar. I've seen article where there was chokidar in one node instance which was sending request to update code in express node instance. Got you, so chokidar and express app will be running in same process in your example.
What to do in watch callback in your example to reload express app? Require "server.js" file that will create server each time? And before require it needs to kill running server? Or how?

Comment: What do you mean "reloading is simple to require again"?